# UIImageview borders

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a freeform border around an image, instead of the typical rectangle border around the image when you drop it into the view controller

Comment: what is freeform border ?

Comment: Will all your images be the same size?

Comment: There is no such thing as freeform border because an image always have a rectangle bounds no matter the pixels it contains. That being said, however you can draw anything with Core Graphics and show it above the image to make it look like it's border. [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: If you're wanting to clip the image on an arbitrary path, see this answer for a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410254/round-top-corners-of-a-uiview-and-add-border/22410814#22410814

Comment: Could you post some code?