# Cell bounds is wrong in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I found out that the cell bounds is always (320, 44) when I dequeue reusable cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier_ActCalendarCell];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
    NSLog(@"%f,%f", cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height);
    return cell;
}
```

Is that designed? When and where can i get the real bounds of cell?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the bounds?

Comment: @chedabob I'm trying to add top round rect for cell, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410254/round-top-corners-of-a-uiview-and-add-border)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSIndexpath  *indexPath=self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect cellFrameInTableView = cell.frame;
```

//Use this to get actual coordinates

```
CGRect cellFrameInWindow = [self convertRect:cellFrameInTableView toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```